# ColdFusion multi instance installation

Tags: coldfusion, multi-instance-deployment

We have a single ColdFusion 10 Tomcat server on Apache with Multi-instance configuration. We have 4 instances. cfusion and cfusion2 are for visitors in a single cluster. The other two are Search instance and Scheduled Job instance. We have a couple of questions.

It does not seem to be obeying the cluster rule and moving clients from instance and instance. Cfusion is clearly on, cfusion2 seems to be stopped. But i seem to have no way of getting it restarted. What am I doing wrong there?

Question 2 how can be assured that scheduled jobs will only run from the scheduled job instance and not be touched by the other 3 instances. I don't seem to be able to delete or disable their reference with the other instances.

Comment: This question is probably better for Server Fault than Stack Overflow, but never mind. You don't give much info, so this is guess work, but does any of the info in these two blog articles help with at least your session stuff: http://cfmlblog.adamcameron.me/2012/11/problem-with-session-replication-with.html, http://cfmlblog.adamcameron.me/2012/11/things-id-never-looked-at-before.html? Note the link in the comments of the latter one where Aaron had more luck. If these aren't relevant, can you expand your question slightly?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by this "But i seem to have no way of getting it restarted."? What OS are you on? What method do you expect to use to start your instance? Clustered instances are just more than one instance with some clustering plopped over them, so how one starts/stops an instance would not be impacted one way or the other. I think your second question should actually be *another question*, btw. And I reckon move both to Server Fault.

Comment: I will use server fault. My explanation of "but i seem to have no way of getting it restarted" is that in the cfadmin, it indicates that cfusion2 is not running, If try to start it, it won't start. if i create a new instance outside the cluster, it will start. I read the blog posts before coming here. i perhaps thought, that there was an "Ah ha!" answer for me. thanks. your blog is of great help.

Comment: Gotcha. Unfortunately I had no probs setting this stuff up when I did the blog stuff, so I have no expertise troubleshooting issues (if you see what I mean). I know someone with more experience, so I'll point them at your Server Fault question. Link?

Comment: Thanks, i took the poor man's way out and deleted the instances and started the process again. crossing my fingers now.